# load class containing dependencies of other classes not in classpath dynamically in web application

Tags: java, web-applications, classloader

I am trying to compile a dynamically created class which has dependencies of other classes, which is created dynamically. But I got classNotFound exception

```
 int errorCode = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(new String[] { "-classpath", "bin", "-cp",
            ".;"+PATHCONST.TOOLS + ";" + PATHCONST.QUARTZ + ";" + PATHCONST.JUNIT + ";" + 
                    + System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
            "-d", PATHCONST.TOMCAT_CLASSES_PATH, className });  
    ClassLoader cload = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File(ClassFilePath).toURI().toURL() },
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()); 

    System.out.println("errorcode and cload : "+errorCode+" "+cload);

    Class c = Class.forName(fileN);
    Object h = c.newInstance();

    Class<?> c1 = cload.loadClass(h.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you have written?

Comment: thanks, I posted the part of code which compiles and loads properly but if I try to add a class that is already complied and loaded by this code I m getting the classnotfound error

Comment: int errorCode = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(new String[] { "-classpath", "bin", "-cp",
            ".;"+PATHCONST.TOOLS + ";" + PATHCONST.QUARTZ + ";" + PATHCONST.JUNIT + ";" + h.getClass()+";"
                    + System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
            "-d", PATHCONST.TOMCAT_CLASSES_PATH, className });

Comment: you can see that he,getClass(), I am adding to the classpath but @ complilation it gives errors. i tried giving fullpath also